# Processing Repeated Bootstrap Modals in Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal, django-crispy-forms

How do people process bootstrap modals in Django that need to be shown on multiple pages? Do you have a special class to handle a second form? Do you use Crispy Forms?

For example, if I have a Contact Us modal that is launched from a navigation bar on all pages in the application, how would I appropriately process that modal information? I can't imagine copying and pasting the same modal form and view code all over. That's clearly not DRY. I would imagine that there would be a way to do this, since it's a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just stick it all in your base.html? Then extend that on all your other templates. Don't understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if I have a Contact Us modal that is launched from a navigation bar on all pages in the application, how would I appropriately process that modal information? I can't imagine copying and pasting the same modal form and view code all over.

Consider using an include statement, so you can write your modal in its own template, then 'include' it in the page you wish to have it reused on. Here's an example, and here's a link to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

```
{% include "app/example-modal.html" %}
```

You then can create a handler in your views file to parse the any requests from the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I took was to do the following:

1. Write my modal in its own template as @ljlozano suggested
2. Put the form in the modal
3. Send the form via the context with a unique name and ensure that all views that use that form would have that name in the context.
4. Set a prefix to the processing view
5. Use JavaScript via AJAX to submit the form to the proper URL (the URL can be stored in the template)

Python Form and View

```
class ContactUsForm(forms.Form):
    pass

class ContactUsView(FormView, TemplateView):
    prefix = "contact_us_form"
 
class HomeView(FormView, TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data.update({"contact_us_form": ContactUsForm(prefix="contact_us_form")})
    

        return context_data
```

Template

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<script type="module" src={% static "contact_us.js" %}></script>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form method="post" name="id_contact_us_form" id="id_contact_us_form" data-form-url={% url "contact_us" %}>
        <label for="contact_us_form-name">Name</label>
        {% render_field contact_us_form.name class+="form-control" placeholder="Your name" %}
        {{ contact_us_form.errors.name }}
    </form>
</div>
```